# What is the set 2 ℕₒ + 1?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, chi-squared

I encountered this notation while reading the following paper: [On the efficient calculation of a linear combination of chi-square random variables with an application in counting string vacua](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/46/50/505202).

In it, one can read

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot figure out the meaning of the set "2 ℕₒ + 1". I suppose it could mean that r must be odd, but I am not sure.
Also, does the summation of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ indicate that the number of chi-squared variables must always be even?

Comment: $2\mathbb N_0+1$ means $\{2n+1\mid n\in\mathbb N_0\}=\{2(0)+1,2(1)+1,2(2)+1,2(3)+1,...\}=\{1,3,5,7,...\}$

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thanks!

would you care to put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: "I suppose it could mean that $r$ must be odd, but I am not sure." - to be more precise, a positive odd integer. But yes.

Comment: When I was in school the notation was $\Bbb N$ the natural numbers zero included (which is the good notation) and $\Bbb N_0=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$, which I've always thought was stupid. It doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Well, both are stupid to me. Almost everyone who is aware of foundations of mathematics would prefer 0∈ℕ and it is trivially unambiguous to use "ℕ$^+$" or "ℕ$_{≠0}$" to denote ℕ∖{0}. Why do people insist on using some ad-hoc notation whose meaning nobody can know immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\mathbb N_0+1$ means $\{2n+1\mid n\in\mathbb N_0\}$

$=\{2\times0+1,2\times1+1,2\times2+1,2\times3+1,\dots\}=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}.$

Indeed, at the top of page 7, the paper you linked says that $r$ has to be odd.